# Using ggplot and tidyverse to arrange the data and plot related answers (with different labels) together

Tags: r, ggplot2

In my study, children and their parents reply to some multiple questions. Questions change in accordance with the respondent, but they are virtually the same.
I want to compare their answers. However, I'm failing to display the bars close as a function of the respondent.

```
ds = data.frame(
  question = c("I like birds", "my baby likes birds", "I like dogs", "My baby likes dogs"),
  resp = c("child","parent"),
  value = rep(c(1,4,3,1),3)
)


ggplot(ds,
       aes(x = question, y = value, fill = resp)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", position = "dodge") +
  stat_summary(geom = "errorbar")
```

Current output
[image: current output]

Desired output

[image: desired output]

(See that the bars from children and their parents are close)
(I have more than 40 questions. Manually reorder levels are possible, but other strategies are welcome)

Answer (score 0):

If you set the levels of the factor in the order you want, they will plot that way on the x-axis.  This just requires that you call `factor()` on question and provide the different values in the desired order.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
ds = data.frame(
  question = c("I like birds", "My baby likes birds", "I like dogs", "My baby likes dogs"),
  resp = c("child","parent"),
  value = rep(c(1,4,3,1),3)
)

ds <- ds %>% 
  mutate(
    question = factor(question, levels=c("I like birds", 
                                              "My baby likes birds", 
                                              "I like dogs", 
                                              "My baby likes dogs")))
  

ggplot(ds,
       aes(x = question, y = value, fill = resp)) +
  geom_bar(stat="summary", position="dodge")
#> No summary function supplied, defaulting to `mean_se()`
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I have more than 40 questions. Manually reordering levels are possible, but other strategies are welcome

Answer (score 0):

you can order the levels of question in your data and then run ggplot:

```
ds$question<-factor(ds$question,levels = c("I like birds","my baby likes birds","I like dogs", "My baby likes dogs"))

ggplot(ds,
       aes(x = question, y = value, fill = resp)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", position = "dodge") +
  stat_summary(geom = "errorbar")
```

output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your questions already appear in the correct order (top >> bottom) in `ds$question`, you can use `unique()` to get the factor-levels right.

```
ds <- ds %>%
  mutate(question.f = factor(question, levels = unique(question)))
         
ggplot(ds,
       aes(x = question.f, y = value, fill = resp)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", position = "dodge") +
  stat_summary(geom = "errorbar")
```

**edit**

Since the questions are mixed, you (hopefully) can use the stringdistance matrix of the questions (if they differ enought from each other). For your sample data, this could mean:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringdist)
# split questions based on the occurence of the substring "my baby"
L <- split(unique(ds$question), f = grepl("my baby", unique(ds$question), ignore.case = TRUE))
# create a stringdist matrix between the two list elements
m <- stringdistmatrix(L[[1]], L[[2]], useNames = TRUE)
#              my baby likes birds My baby likes dogs
# I like birds                   8                 12
# I like dogs                   12                  8

# pair the questions with minimal distances together
colorder <- c(rbind(rownames(m), colnames(m)[apply(m, 1, which.min)]))

ds <- ds %>%
  mutate(question.f = factor(question, levels = colorder))

ggplot(ds,
       aes(x = question.f, y = value, fill = resp)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", position = "dodge") +
  stat_summary(geom = "errorbar")
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the case. Questions are mixed.

Comment: I updated the answer with a stringdistance-solution, You will (probably) have to tweak it in order to get it working on your production data. I hope I added enough explanation to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex to make the responses for children and parents match:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ds %>%
  mutate(
    question = gsub("i like|my baby likes", "likes", tolower(question))
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = question, y = value, fill = resp)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", position = "dodge") + 
  stat_summary(geom = "errorbar", position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After re-arranging the data and using some local strategies, I could figure out a solution. Thanks to everyone. I feel happy if someone improves this code.

```r
library(tidyverse)
ds = data.frame(
  question = c("I like birds", "my baby likes birds", "I like dogs", "My baby likes dogs"),
  resp = c("child","parent"),
  value = rep(c(1,4,3,1),3))
  
ds %>%
  mutate(across(c(question,resp), as.factor)) %>%
  group_by(resp) %>%
  mutate(id = cur_group_id()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(question) %>%
  mutate(id2 = cur_group_id()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  {mutate(.,item =  ifelse(.$id == 2, id2 - max(.$id2[.$id==1])  , id2)) }%>%
  ggplot(.,   aes(question, y = value, fill = resp))+
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", position = "dodge")+
  stat_summary(geom="errorbar", fun.data = mean_se, 
               position = position_dodge(0.95), width = .5) +
  facet_grid(. ~ item, space="free_x", scales="free_x", switch="x") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, vjust=1, hjust=1),
        strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.background = element_rect(fill=NA,colour=NA),
        panel.spacing.x=unit(0.15,"cm")) +
  expand_limits(x=-0.5)
#> No summary function supplied, defaulting to `mean_se()`
#> No summary function supplied, defaulting to `mean_se()`
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>